# Terminal has been unstable since last upgrade (OSX 10.12.2)

Tags: terminal, crash

I have had repeated Terminal.app crashes while working with the command line, whether on the local computer or shelled into a Linux VPS.

Is this a known issue? Are there alternative CLI terminal applications that will behave like terminal, only at least being more stable?

Thanks,

Comment: I would recommend you [iTerm](https://www.iterm2.com).

Comment: @Helio, please restate your comment as an answer so I can accept it. Thanks...

Comment: Here you go! However, it doesn't deserve to be an answer. If you provide me more information about the crash, maybe I can help you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To answer your other question: "Is this a known issue?", I have been having problems with Terminal.app crashing too, and [this post](https://discussions.apple.com/message/31309932#message31309932) seems to suggest that the issue is known to Apple.

Answer (score 0):

I never had a crash on the Terminal application because I never used it (or mostly never). So, I can't answer your first question.

About your second question, yes, there is a objectively better terminal emulator for macOS:

> **[iTerm 2](https://www.iterm2.com/)** is a replacement for Terminal and the successor to iTerm. It
>   works on Macs with macOS 10.8 or newer. iTerm2 brings the terminal
>   into the modern age with features you never knew you always wanted.

[image: screenshot]

I've been using iTerm 2 since I have the iMac and I never missed any feature of the Terminal application. Also, iTerm 2 is open source software.